# SQL Mirroring synchronize logins and agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

We have just started using SQL Server mirroring for several clients on SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard.

We've got the SQL Server mirroring working fine however now we run into the issue of replicating logins, and agent jobs. I found [**this article**](http://www.msbicoe.com/post/2012/04/05/Automatically-Transfer-and-Synchronize-SQL-Server-logins-SIDs-Passwords-and-Permissions.aspx) which shows how to synchronize logins but I wasn't able to get this working. I couldn't specify the source and destination server.

Anyone run into the issue of synchronizing logins and agent jobs after having databases mirrored? If so, what workaround have you come up with?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jobs are easy to script, but I don't know of any turnkey solution to make that *automatic*. I suppose when someone manually makes a change to a job on the primary, they should also make the change on the secondary. For the logins, try [this script from Robert Davis](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror).

Comment: Just ensure that the change is reflected on the mirrored end?

Comment: In the end one of my colleagues came up with an stored [proc that stored the username and passwords in a table so the mirrored instance would have that table as well. Whenever the database fails over to the other server, all we have to do is run another stored proc which restores the credentials from that table.